# Criar botão sair usando onClick

Tags: android, button

Estou com um problema em um botão no android. Preciso criar uma botão de sair, porém quando o botão é selecionado aparece um erro.

Esta é a classe Dashboard:

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.layout_dashboard);

}

public void sairApp(View view){
    this.finish();
}
```

}

Esse é o botão:

```
<Button

      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/sair"
      android:onClick="sairApp"
      android:text="@string/sair"
      android:textColor="#062f3c"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Esse é o erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sairApp(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button
                                                                    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4506)
                                                                    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4470)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5225)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21195)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É mais fácil e melhor na usabilidade da aplicação que você atribua um ID ao botão e use o OnClickListener para identificar o click, se não você irá precisar criar um método para cada Button do seu layout.

Exemplo na declaração do XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/finish_app"
    ... />
```

Exemplo do Java:

```
Button finish_app = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish_app);
finish_app.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        this.finish();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você definiu algum tema no seu XML? Se tiver definido então o problema pode ser este. Olha se está resposta te ajuda: [onClick não funciona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525644/could-not-find-a-method-onclick-fooview-first-time-running-on-android-lollip) 
 de qualquer forma, não recomendo definir os métodos no XML, isso dificulta o reuso dos XML.  Embora mais trabalhoso, é sempre melhor definir o click via código mesmo.